# Dynamically addition elements to Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need dynamically add elements to Angularjs.
I added them successfully.
But I can't pass their values to the variables of scope.
I need to create the elements in a separate factory instead of creating inside the directive.

`fieldsFactory` do add elements for input data. These elements must provide data to array `data` in scope `wrapper` directive.

Can you help?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('fieldsFactory', fieldsFactory)
  .directive('wrapper', wrapper);


function wrapper(fieldsFactory) {
  return {
    template: `
    <div>
        <button ng-click="addField('select')">Add select</button>
        <button ng-click="addField('input')">Add input</button>
        <pre ng-bind="data"></pre>
      </div>
    `,
    link: wrapperLinkFn
  }
}

function wrapperLinkFn(
  scope,
  iElement,
  iAttrs,
  iCtrl,
  transcludeFn
) {
  scope.addField = addField;
  scope.fieldsCounter = 0;

  var fieldsFactory = iElement.injector().get('fieldsFactory');

  function addField(fieldType) {
    fieldsFactory(scope, iElement, fieldType, scope.fieldsCounter);
    scope.fieldsCounter++;
  }
}

function fieldsFactory() {
  return function(scope, iElement, fieldType, fieldsCounter) {
    var field;
    switch (fieldType) {
      case 'input':
        field = `<div><input ng-model="data[${fieldsCounter}]"><div>`;
        break;
      case 'select':
        field = `
        <div>
          <select ng-model="data[${fieldsCounter}]">
            <option value="select1">select1</option>
            <option value="select2">select2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        `;
        break;
      default:
        field = '';
    }
    iElement.injector().invoke(function($compile) {
      iElement.append($compile(field)(scope));
    });
  }
}
angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <wrapper></wrapper>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My steps:

- defined the isolateScope for created elements

  ```js
  var isolateScope = iElement.scope().$new(true);
  ```
- defined variable in isolateScope them to store inputed data
- defined function `ng-change` that call function at parent scope

  ```js
  isolateScope.onChange = function() {
     iElement.scope().setFieldValue(fieldsCounter, isolateScope.fieldValue);
  }
  ```
- defined the function in parent scope that set value for specific key and start $digest cycle for parent scope

  ```js
  function setFieldValue(key, value) {
    scope.data[key] = value;
  }
  ```
- defined the function that bind data value

  ```js
  function getData() {
    return scope.data;
  }
  ```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('fieldsFactory', fieldsFactory)
  .directive('wrapper', wrapper);


function wrapper(fieldsFactory) {
  return {
    template: `
    <div class="container m-2">
        <button 
          ng-click="addField('select')"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        >Add select</button>
        <button 
          ng-click="addField('input')"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        >Add input</button>
        <div class="list-group mt-2 w-50">
          <div
            ng-repeat="field in getData()"
            ng-bind="field"
            class="list-group-item"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `,
    link: wrapperLinkFn
  }
}

function wrapperLinkFn(
  scope,
  iElement
) {
  scope.addField = addField;
  scope.setFieldValue = setFieldValue;
  scope.getData = getData;
  scope.fieldsCounter = 0;
  scope.data = {};

  function setFieldValue(key, value) {
    scope.data[key] = value;
  }
  
  function getData() {
    return scope.data;
  }

  var fieldsFactory = iElement.injector().get('fieldsFactory');

  function addField(fieldType) {
    fieldsFactory(scope, iElement, fieldType, scope.fieldsCounter);
    scope.fieldsCounter++;
  }
}

function fieldsFactory() {
  return function(scope, iElement, fieldType, fieldsCounter) {
    var field;
    switch (fieldType) {
      case 'input':
        field = `
        <div class="w-50 m-2">
          <input 
            ng-change="onChange()" 
            ng-model="fieldValue"
            class="form-control"
          >
        <div>
        `;
        break;
      case 'select':
        field = `
        <div class="w-50 m-2">
          <select 
            ng-change="onChange()" 
            ng-model="fieldValue"
            class="form-control"
          >
            <option value="select1">select1</option>
            <option value="select2">select2</option>
          </select>
          <pre ng-bind="getData()"></pre>
        </div>
        `;
        break;
      default:
        field = '';
    }
    iElement.injector().invoke(function($compile) {
      var isolateScope = iElement.scope().$new(true);
      isolateScope.onChange = function() {
        iElement.scope().setFieldValue(fieldsCounter, isolateScope.fieldValue);
        console.log(iElement.scope().data);
      }
      
      iElement.append($compile(field)(isolateScope));
    });
  }
}
angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <wrapper></wrapper>
</div>
```